# OpenCart SEO isnt working even with rewrite mode enabled and SEO URLs = yes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, opencart, opencart2.x

I have opencart installed with ubuntu 14.04, my apache config file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/
        <Directory /var/www/example.com>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <ifmodule mod_evasive20.c>
 DOSHashTableSize 3097
 DOSPageCount 20
 DOSSiteCount 100
 DOSPageInterval 1
 DOSSiteInterval 1
 DOSBlockingPeriod 10
 DOSLogDir /var/log/mod_evasive
 #DOSWhitelist 127.0.0.1
</ifmodule>
        ErrorLog /var/log/example-error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.

        CustomLog /var/log/example-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and my sudo vi /var/www/example.com/.htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When i make a search on my web, am still getting the whole url like:

```
http://example.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=asdsa&search_type=0&limit=6
```

or

```
http://example.com/index.php?route=information/contact
```

This should be the right installation to get an SEO friendly urls, but it's not working fine.. any help?

Answer (score 0):

To set SEO URLS

1. Add the SEO keywords to all products and categories (unique
   keywords).
2. Switch on SEO URLs - Go to System>Settings>Server>Use SEO URLs. You only
   get this option on the DEFAULT store.
3. Edit the .htaccess file.

> RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?*route*=$1 [L,QSA]

Also, refer link [Enable SEO friendly URLs in Opencart](http://themes.eshopalot.com/enable-seo-friendly-urls-in-opencart/)

Comment: I mentioned that i did all of this and nothing happened. maybe it's a problem on my opencart installation ill try a new one and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

change SEO url to no 
 from System>setting>server